# Obtain number of days by different months using 2 dates

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset `input` and I want to convert it into dataset `output`. Basically I am trying to manipulate the dataset so that I am able to split the number of days between 2 dates into different months. Wondering if this can be done in R?

R code for creating the datasets below for easy reference.

```
library('data.table')
input=data.table(SerialNum=c(1,2),StartDate=c('28/01/2015','28/01/2015'),EndDate=c('03/02/2015','03/03/2015'))

#       SerialNum  StartDate    EndDate
#    1:         1 28/01/2015 03/02/2015
#    2:         2 28/01/2015 03/03/2015


output=data.table(SerialNum=c(1,1,2,2,2),
                  StartDate=c('28/01/2015','28/01/2015','28/01/2015','28/01/2015','28/01/2015'),
                  EndDate=c('03/02/2015','03/02/2015','03/03/2015','03/03/2015','03/03/2015'),
                  MMMYY=c('Jan15','Feb15','Jan15','Feb15','Mar15'),
                  Days=c(4,3,4,28,3))

#       SerialNum  StartDate    EndDate MMMYY Days
#    1:         1 28/01/2015 03/02/2015 Jan15    4
#    2:         1 28/01/2015 03/02/2015 Feb15    3
#    3:         2 28/01/2015 03/03/2015 Jan15    4
#    4:         2 28/01/2015 03/03/2015 Feb15   28
#    5:         2 28/01/2015 03/03/2015 Mar15    3
```

Comment: I don't understand this part: "split the number of days between 2 dates into different months". Don't you just want the number of days between the two dates? What does "into different months" mean?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I am actually trying to calculate the number of days patient has stayed in the hospital but segmented by month. For example, if patient stayed from 28Jan2015 to 03Feb2015, he/she would have stayed 4 days in Jan and 3 days in Feb. In order to do a pivot table to know how many patient days are used in Jan and Feb respectively, I would need to manipulate the dataset to give me 2 observations. 1 for Jan and 1 for Feb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a sequence from `StartDate` to `EndDate` and extract a month-year variable from that (`mnth` in the example below). Next you summarise by `serialNum` and the newly created month-year variable (`mnth`):

```
input[, .(mnth = format(seq(StartDate,EndDate,"day"), "%b%y")),
      by = .(SerialNum, StartDate, EndDate)
      ][, .N, by = .(SerialNum, StartDate, EndDate, mnth)]
```

which will give you:

```
   SerialNum  StartDate    EndDate  mnth  N
1:         1 2015-01-28 2015-02-03 jan15  4
2:         1 2015-01-28 2015-02-03 feb15  3
3:         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 jan15  4
4:         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 feb15 28
5:         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 mrt15  3
```

If you `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns are not formatted as dates yet, you can convert them to date format with:

```
input[, `:=` (StartDate = as.Date(StartDate,"%d/%m/%Y"),
              EndDate = as.Date(EndDate,"%d/%m/%Y"))]

# or with the 'lubridate' package like @Titolondon used
library(lubridate)
input[, `:=` (StartDate = dmy(StartDate), EndDate = dmy(EndDate))]
```

---

Used data:

```
input <- data.table(SerialNum = c(1,2),
                    StartDate = as.Date(c('28/01/2015','28/01/2015'),"%d/%m/%Y"),
                    EndDate = as.Date(c('03/02/2015','03/03/2015'),"%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I understand .N is used because it's the difference in number of days. How can I modify the code if I were to have both dates and time so that I can obtain fractional days?

Answer (score 1):

This is a base R solution, rather than than a `data.table` solution: `sapply` operates separately on each value of `SerialNum`. We create a sequence of dates from `StartDate` to `EndDate`, then count the number of dates within each month. The whole thing is wrapped in `do.call(rbind, ...)` to turn the resulting list into a single data frame.

```
library(lubridate)

input = data.frame(SerialNum=c(1,2),StartDate=c('28/01/2015','28/01/2015'),EndDate=c('03/02/2015','03/03/2015'), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

input[,2:3] = lapply(input[,2:3], dmy)

do.call(rbind,
        sapply(unique(input$SerialNum), function(i) {

          start = input[input$SerialNum==i,"StartDate"]
          end = input[input$SerialNum==i, "EndDate"]

          dates = seq(start, end, by="1 day")

          data.frame(SerialNum=i, StartDate=start, EndDate=end, 
                     MMMYY=unique(format(dates, "%b%y")),
                     Days=sapply(split(dates, droplevels(month(dates, label=TRUE))), length))

        }, simplify=FALSE))

     SerialNum  StartDate    EndDate MMMYY Days
Jan          1 2015-01-28 2015-02-03 Jan15    4
Feb          1 2015-01-28 2015-02-03 Feb15    3
Jan1         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 Jan15    4
Feb1         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 Feb15   28
Mar          2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 Mar15    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` and `lubridate`:

```
library(data.table)

input = data.table(
  SerialNum = c(1, 2),
  StartDate = c('28/01/2015', '28/01/2015'),
  EndDate = c('03/02/2015', '03/03/2015')
)
```

Work with `lubridate` for date manipulation

```
library(lubridate)
```

If not already in `POSIXct`, convert your column with `lubridate` functions

```
input[, StartDate := dmy(StartDate)]
input[, EndDate := dmy(EndDate)]
```

*Trick* : create a sequence of date between `StartDate` and `EndDate` by `SerialNum`

```
DT <- input[, .(seqDate = StartDate + days(0:(EndDate - StartDate))), 
            by = .(SerialNum, StartDate, EndDate)]
```

Derive `MMMYY` column from this new date sequence. I used `month.abb`to have good abbreviation but you could use `MMMYY = format(seqDate, "%b%y")` if you are in good locale setting

```
DT[, MMMYY := paste0(month.abb[month(seqDate)], format(seqDate, "%y"))]
```

Count number of days by month (column `MMMYY`)

```
output = DT[, .(Days = .N), by = .(SerialNum, StartDate, EndDate, MMMYY)]
output
#>    SerialNum  StartDate    EndDate MMMYY Days
#> 1:         1 2015-01-28 2015-02-03 Jan15    4
#> 2:         1 2015-01-28 2015-02-03 Feb15    3
#> 3:         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 Jan15    4
#> 4:         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 Feb15   28
#> 5:         2 2015-01-28 2015-03-03 Mar15    3
```